# How to delete the div in a dynamically added sortable input boxes and indexing in front of the added input

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

```js
 $('#add').click(function() {
                  var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name"/><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value" placeholder="Email"/><a href="a"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></a><input type="button" class="form-control" class="Minus" value="-" />' + ($('.con div').length + 1) + '</div>');
                  x.appendTo('#form .con') // the length is not working here if I use it in the front of the div while declairng the variable.
                });

                $('.Minus').on('click', '#rem .Minus', function () {
                    $(this).closest(".fruit").remove();
                    });
         
                    $("span").sortable({
                    connectWith: ".con"
                }).disableSelection();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

 <div>
          
 <button id="add">add another option</button>
  <form id="form" class="form-inline">
    <span class="con">
        <div class="ui-state-highlight"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value" placeholder="Email"/><a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span><input type="button" class="form-control" class="Minus" value="delete" />
        </a>

</div>
       
    </span>
  </form>
   </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I'm trying to add index and delete individually added rows.I tried to use length of the div but its not firing if I append it in the front of the input boxes.Here's the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4P6HWu9jVTmZhOnEhMdb?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight">' + ($('.con div').length + 1) + '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name"/><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value" placeholder="Email"/><a href="a"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></a><input type="button" class="form-control Minus" value="-" /></div>');
  x.appendTo('#form .con') // the length is not working here if I use it in the front of the div while declairng the variable.



});

$('.con').on('click', '.Minus', function() {
  $(this).parents(".ui-state-highlight").remove();
});

$("span").sortable({
  connectWith: ".con"
}).disableSelection();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

  <div>

    <button id="add">add another option</button>
    <form id="form" class="form-inline">
      <span class="con">
        <div class="ui-state-highlight"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value" placeholder="Email"/><a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span>
      <input type="button" class="form-control" class="Minus" value="delete" />
      </a>

  </div>

  </span>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

1. You had double `class` declarations, so I merged them to get `form-control Minus` class.
2. Also fixed selectors for `.on()` handler.

EDIT:
Your new row markup is defined by

```
var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name"/><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value" placeholder="Email"/><a href="a"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></a><input type="button" class="form-control Minus" value="-" />' + ($('.con div').length + 1) + '</div>');
```

To move the index to the front, move this `($('.con div').length + 1)` to the front like so:

```
var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight">' + ($('.con div').length + 1) + '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.field" placeholder="Name"/><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value" placeholder="Email"/><a href="a"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></span></a><input type="button" class="form-control Minus" value="-" /></div>');
```

Comment: can you tell me a what can I use to make it have numbering in the front.

Comment: I have updated both the answer and the code snippet.